Failed to add foreign key in MySQL database
Hello I have this my SQL code:
create table expedition(
  name varchar(50) ,
  subject varchar(50) ,
  timespan float not null ,
  location varchar(50) ,
  primary key(name,subject,timespan,location)
);
create table county(
  name varchar(50) ,
  primary key(name)
);
create table person(
  address varchar(50) ,
  primary key(address)
);

create table representative(
  id integer unique not null  ,
  name varchar(50)  ,
  primary key(id)    
);

create table company(
  id integer unique not null ,
  name varchar(50) ,
  afm varchar(50) ,
  address varchar(50) ,
  sizey integer not null ,
  primary key(address,afm)  ,
  foreign key(id) references representative(id)
);

create table representator(
  id integer not null ,
  nameOrAddress varchar(50) ,
  primary key(id) ,
  foreign key(nameOrAddress) references county(name) ,
  foreign key(nameOrAddress) references person(address)

);
create table organiser(
  nameOrAddress varchar(50) ,
  id integer not null ,  
  primary key(id) ,
  foreign key(nameOrAddress) references company(name)  ,
  foreign key(nameOrAddress) references person(address) 
);

When I try to run this I get this error:
`ERROR 1822 (HY000) at line 41: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'organiser_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'company'
[Execution complete with exit code 1]`
Is it due to the fact that name isnt a primary key of company?
And I have attributes of different entities named the same , I keep using the word "id" for different entities.
I know that inside the declaration of a table the attribute "id" is local however when I use the refer to the foreign key for example in here:
`create table company(
...
foreign key(id) references representative(id)
...
);
obviously I want the "id" of the "representative(id)" to not be the local variable of the table company but the local variable of the table representative so is my syntax correct or not?And if it is not how should I change it?
`

The structure is terrible. Read about database structure design .. at least something.

@Akina hi!wdym by that?

You use natural keys which is not reasonable in most cases (including your case). Use synthetic AI PK instead.


Is it due to the fact that name isnt a primary key of company?

Yes. A foreign key must reference either the primary key or a non-null unique key of the referenced table.
But that's only one of the problems in your example.
Another problem is that you're attempting to use foreign key constraints for polymorphic associations (e.g. nameOrAddress). By using two foreign keys referencing different tables, you're requiring that every value in the nameOrAddress column must exist in the key of both referenced tables. I doubt this is your intention. Basically, if you use polymorphic associations, you can't use foreign key constraints.
You're also confused by the scope of column names, like id. You give an example:
create table company( ... foreign key(id) references representative(id) ... );

Be assured that the first id is the foreign key column in the company table, and the second id is in fact the primary key column of the representative table.
This example is also probably not what you intended, because conventionally id is a primary key of a table (I say conventionally, because there's nothing meaningful about the name id, I just mean that many developers follow a habit of naming their primary key column id).
But if company.id references representative.id, and both are the primary key of the respective table, this means that only one row in company can reference a given representative. The tables are in a 1-to-1 relationship. Is it true that no representative can ever represent more than one company?
There are other puzzling details in your design. Like person.address being the primary key of that table. This means no two people can share an address. Is this your intention?

A foreign key must reference either the primary key or a non-null unique key of the referenced table. In MySQL, rather than most DBMSs, the index must exist only, non-NULL and UNIQUE properties are optional. https://dbfiddle.uk/GEMzvszY

@Akina, That road leads to madness!

MySQL is well-known as "lamer-friendly".

I mean a foreign key that references a non-unique key is not standard SQL. It causes weird cases, like if a FK value references two rows, what happens if you delete one of those rows in the parent table? Is it permitted? If you have a cascading FK, should it cascade? It's best to avoid such non-standard FK's.

what happens if you delete one of those rows in the parent table? The server prevents the deletion/updation. https://dbfiddle.uk/T6QJ3HWD

@BillKarwin I agree with your reaction in principle, but Akina is right, mysql allows foreign keys to be created on any indexes.

The error here is triggered by foreign key referencing company.name column, which is not part of any index. The foreign key should reference the id column in company table.

@Shadow Yes, and C++ allows us to overload operators, which means we could make + into * and * into +. Should we ever do that, because the language allows it? No, of course not!
